# Show/hide a table using ngrx in angular

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I want to show/hide a table if the checkbox is checked using ngrx with angular 8. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: In addition, if I have multiple sections of table getting rendered, if that individual section can be hide/show with checkbox using NgRx, please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Simply define an action, a reducer and a selector for the feature.

```js
import {createAction, props, createReducer, on, Action, createFeatureSelector, createSelector} from '@ngrx/store';

export const setCheckbox = createAction('[checkbox] set', props<{value: boolean}>());

export interface CheckboxState {
    value: boolean;
}

export const initialState: CheckboxState = {
    value: false,
};

export const reducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(setCheckbox, (state, {value}) => ({...state, value})),
);

export function checkboxReducer(state: CheckboxState = initialState, action: Action) {
    return reducer(state, action);
}

export const selectCheckboxFeature = createFeatureSelector<CheckboxState>('checkbox');

export const selectCheckboxValue = createSelector(
    selectCheckboxFeature,
    state => state.value,
);
```

import them in `AppModule`

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {checkboxReducer} from 'src/app/entity/store/user/user.actions';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({
            checkbox: checkboxReducer,
        }),
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

add selector and dispatcher in AppComponent

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {selectCheckboxValue, setCheckbox} from 'src/app/entity/store/user/user.actions';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
    const checkbox$ = this.store.select(selectCheckboxValue);

    constructor(private readonly store: Store<any>) {
    }

    toggle(value: boolean) {
        this.store.dispatch(setCheckbox({value}));
    }
}
```

and display in in the template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="checkbox$ | async as value">
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="value" (change)="toggle(!value)">
</ng-container>
```

profit